# Как использовать (запускать) class в цикле

Tags: javascript, классы, ecmascript-6

> Внесу некоторые изменения в вопрос, опишу поподробнее....

Коллеги, есть такой вот  пример. В котором я создаю `class CreateBlockInfo`.
не думаю что надо объяснять, что именно происходит в данном классе.

```js
let info = document.querySelectorAll('.info');
class CreateBlockInfo {
  constructor(elem) {
    this.fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    this.element = document.createElement(elem);
  }
  Append(parent) {
    this.fragment.appendChild(this.element);
    parent.appendChild(this.fragment)
  }
}

//Потом создаю экземпляр класса  runCreateBlockInfo
let runCreateBlockInfo = new CreateBlockInfo('span');
// и вот далее я пытаюсь запустить экземпляр класса в цикле
// я хочу в каждый элемент info  вставить созданный span
for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  runCreateBlockInfo.Append(info[i]);
}

// рузультат такой, только в последний элемент info вставляется span 

console.log(info[0].childNodes);
console.log(info[1].childNodes);
console.log(info[2].childNodes);
```

```html
<p class="info"></p>
<p class="info"></p>
<p class="info"></p>
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, что если в цикл создавать новый объект

```
for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  let runCreateBlockInfo = new CreateBlockInfo();
  runCreateBlockInfo.Append(info[i]);
}
```

То я получу, то чего хочу.

Но, тут есть одно  НО...  Простите за выражение, нутром чую, что это не верно.
Так как я создаю один и тот же `Объект` несколько раз.  А мне кажется, что надо один раз проинициализировать новый **объект**. А потом использовать его сколько душе угодно.

Коллеги, вопрос -  верно ли мои умозаключения выше и если да, как выйти из ситуации???

Или может я не верное рассуждаю?  Помогите разобраться.

Comment: а какой результат должен быть в итоге?

Comment: @Grundy, я хочу в каждый элемент `class='info'` вставить `span`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [`.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) **не создает новый элемент**. Если элемент уже есть на странице, то он **перенесется** из одного места, в другое.

Чтобы решить это, можно создавать элемент span каждый раз, либо клонировать тот, который создан в конструкторе, например:

```js
let info = document.querySelectorAll('.info');
class CreateBlockInfo {
  constructor(elem) {
    this.fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    this.element = document.createElement(elem);
  }
  Append(parent) {
    this.fragment.appendChild(this.element.cloneNode());
    parent.appendChild(this.fragment)
  }
}

//Потом создаю экземпляр класса  runCreateBlockInfo
let runCreateBlockInfo = new CreateBlockInfo('span');
// и вот далее я пытаюсь запустить экземпляр класса в цикле
// я хочу в каждый элемент info  вставить созданный span
for (let i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
  runCreateBlockInfo.Append(info[i]);
}

// рузультат такой, только в последний элемент info вставляется span 

console.log(info[0].childNodes);
console.log(info[1].childNodes);
console.log(info[2].childNodes);
```

```css
span::before {
  content: "span"
}
```

```html
<p class="info"></p>
<p class="info"></p>
<p class="info"></p>
```

Comment: Вот чувствовал же, что что-то упустил...  Благодарю...